# how to open a shell window output print real time debug information in python

Tags: python, shell, debugging, redirect

Can I open a shell window for print debug information in python without break the execute sequence of code?

for example:

```
def foo(b):
    print b

for a in range(0, 100):
    print a       # normally this will be used for on-the-fly simple debugging purpose 
                  # and will mess the console output of foo()          
    foo(a)
```

can I do something like:

```
newshell = <new cmd.exe or bash>

for a in range(0, 100):
    newshell.print(a)       # information will be printed to new opened shell  
    foo(a)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me get this straight? You want to consoles opened? One with real output and another one with errors right? What OS are you using?

Comment: @Paulo Bu,  I want a cross platform solution, win32 is preferred, since *nix will be a bit easier due to it have /dev/tty vty pty ... but win32 has no such device.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use python logging. http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html
2. Simply write to file and from a terminal do: $ tail -f output.txt
3. Write to the already opened terminal in your box (i.e. linux), writing to the file descriptor /dev/pts/X (with X: 1,2..., you can see the proper number with $ who)

Comment: Thanks, can 'logging' send log to another shell window? i do not want to involve another temp file.

Comment: Yes, it can. But it's a quite weird. Just do logging.FileHandler('/dev/pts/X'). X is the number of the opened terminal.

Comment: Mine only apply in *nix systems. "pts" could be "tty", it depends. See command $ who.

Comment: thanks, it only works in *nix. I am looking for a simple solution support both WIN32 and *nix (maybe named pipe/socket/subprocess)

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a *shell* just to print something. You could use a [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) Text [widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, END

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

def foo(b):
    print b

for a in range(0, 100):
    text.insert(END, str(a)+"\n")
    text.see(END)
    text.update()
    foo(a)

text.wait_window()  # wait until we close the window
```